# How can I stop my submit button from taking up the width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, button, form-submit

Following is my HTML form code :

```
<div class="content">
   <form method="POST" action="<%= url_for :controller => :Settings, :action => :login_mcommerce %>">
     <% if @msg %>
         <div class="error-message"><%= @msg %></div>
     <% end %>

     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <label for="login" class="itemLabel">User ID</label>
       <input type="text" id="login" name="login" class="itemValue"  />
     </div>
     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <label for="password">Password</label>
       <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="itemValue"  />
     </div>
     <div>
     <input type="submit" value="Login" />
   </div>
     </form>
 </div>
```

The submit button is taking the width of the screen, and I want to decrease its width. How would I do that?[image]

**CSS** :

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
    width: inherit;
    height: 100%;
}

.toolbar .noButton {
    display: none;
}

.content ul {
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.content ul li {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

.content ul li span {
    display: block;
}

.content ul.settings li div.itemLabel span.title {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.0em;
}

/* header */

.pageTitle h1 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

/* toolbar */

.toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #aebbcb), color-stop(0.5, #8094ae), color-stop(1.0, #6e84a2));
}

.toolbar div {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.toolbar .leftItem {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50px;
}

.toolbar .centerItem {
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 30px;
}

.toolbar .rightItem {
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 50px;
}

.toolbar a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.toolbar .backButton {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 16px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(/public/images/backButton.png) 0 5 0 13 stretch stretch;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px 16px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px 6px;
    border-width: 0 5px 0 13px;
    width: auto;
    font-size: .9em;
    z-index: 3;
}

.toolbar .deleteButton,
.toolbar .regularButton,
.toolbar .blueButton {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: .9em;
    border-left: #5e7088 1px solid;
    border-right: #5e7088 1px solid;
    border-top: #34404e 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #34404e 1px solid;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

.toolbar .deleteButton {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #aebbcb), color-stop(0.5, #8094ae), color-stop(1.0, #6e84a2));
}

.toolbar .regularButton {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #92a4bc), color-stop(0.5, #476997), color-stop(1.0, #4e6c92));
}

.toolbar .blueButton {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #6f96e9), color-stop(0.5, #3366cc), color-stop(1.0, #3366cc));
    border: #1a49b3 1px solid;
}

.content {
    background: #EEEEFF;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.content form button.createButton {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #2289EF
}

.content .standardButton {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    background: white;
    color: #436395;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.content .standardButton a {
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    color: #436395;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}

/*  text styles  */

.darkBlue {
    color: #7287A4;
}

.content h2.groupTitle {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 8px;
    color: #565E70;
}

/* lists */

.content ul {
    border-top: 1px solid #848284;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.content ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #848284;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.content ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.content ul li > span {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.content ul li a:active {
    background: transperent;
}

.content ul li span.title {
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}

.content ul li div.itemLabel {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 10px;
}

.content ul li div.itemValue {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 0;
}

.content ul li a span.disclosure_indicator {
    background: url('/public/images/iphone/disclosure.png') no-repeat center right;
    height: 25px;
    width: 35px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline;
}

.content ul li a span.detail_disclosure {
    background: url('/public/images/iphone/disclosure_detail.png') no-repeat center right;
    height: 27px;
    width: 34px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline;
}

.content ul li a img {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100px;
}

/* Forms */

.content form {
    padding: 5px 0 75px 0;
    border: none;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: medium;
}

.content form ul {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #878787;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.content form ul li {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #848284;
    line-height: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content form ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}

.content form ul li label {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 20px 0 10px;
    width: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.content form ul li label.fieldLabel {
    display: none;
}

.content form input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 45%;
    border: 0;
}

.content form input, .content form select {
    height: 40px;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.content form input[type="text"], .content form input[type="password"] {
    width: 180px;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1067C1;
}

.content form input[type="checkbox"] {
    background: url('/public/images/iphone/switch.png') no-repeat center;
    background-position-y: -27px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 94px;
}

.content form input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-position-y: 0;
}

.content form input[type="radio"] {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 290px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}

.content form input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background: url('/public/images/iphone/radiobutton.png') no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 100%;
    background-position-y: 50%;
}

.content form select {
    background: url('/public/images/iphone/select.png') no-repeat right;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content form textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: medium;
    width: 280px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

/* Settings */

.content ul.settings {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.content ul.settings li.alertMessage {
    text-align: center;
}

.content ul.settings li span {
    line-height: 40px;
}

.content ul.settings li.alertMessage span.message {
    color: red;
}

.content ul.settings li span.clientID {
    margin-left: 4px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.content ul.settings li div.itemLabel span.title {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.content .reset {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.content .reset h4 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin: 0 8px;
    color: #565E70;
}



/* Override some styles provided by iphone.css to make them match the real iPhone more closely. */

.toolbar {
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1, rgb(16,103,193)), color-stop(1, rgb(17,85,169)), color-stop(1, rgb(0,33,117)), color-stop(1, rgb(0,17,90)));
    border-top: 1px solid #CDD5Df;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2D3642;
}

.toolbar a { font-weight: bold; }

.pageTitle { width: 50%; margin:0 auto; }

.pageTitle h1 {
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0px -1px 0;
    width: 50%;  /* Should match pageTitle's width. */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

/* --- Controls the switcher buttons, trying to emulate the native switcher control. --- */

/* Use the following pattern in your HTML code to implement it:

  <div class="switcher">
    <div class="ls-button ls-pressed ls-left"><a href="#">Left Button</a></div>
    <div class="ls-button ls-center"><a href="#">Center Button</a></div>
    <div class="ls-button ls-right ls-disabled"><a href="#">Right Button</a></div>
  </div>

  */

/* Use on the div containing your button options. */
.switcher {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    height:30px;
}

/* All button divs must contain an <a> tag with the button's label in it. */
.switcher a {
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px -1px 0;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:smaller;
}

/* Include the .ls-button style on each button div. */
.switcher .ls-button {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(171,185,202)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(130,151,175)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(118,139,167)), color-stop(1, rgb(120,141,169)));
    width:80px;  /* NOTE: If you only want to use 2 buttons, increase width to something more like 125px, and change margin to 0 -3px. */
    height:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    margin:0 -2px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
}

/* Indicates the currently active (pressed) button. */
.switcher .ls-pressed {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(142,164,193)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(88,119,162)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(71,105,153)), color-stop(1, rgb(74,108,152)));
}

.switcher .ls-left {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.switcher .ls-center {
    border-right:none;
    border-left:none;
}

.switcher .ls-right {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

/* If an option should not be available, you can use the .ls-disabled class to gray it out. */
.switcher .ls-disabled {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(158,158,158)), color-stop(0.95, rgb(204,204,204)))
}

/* However, even with disabled classes you must still include an <a> tag. Just have it go href="#" */
.switcher .ls-disabled a {
    color:#f0f0f0;
}

/* ---------- JQM theme customization ------------- */
.ui-bar-a {
    border: 1px solid       #ccc;
    background:             #bbb;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #aebbcb), color-stop(0.5, #8094ae), color-stop(1.0, #6e84a2));
/*
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ddd), to(#bbb));
*/
}
.ui-bar-a,
.ui-bar-a input,
.ui-bar-a select,
.ui-bar-a textarea,
.ui-bar-a button {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ui-bar-a .ui-link-inherit {
    color:                  #333;
}
.ui-bar-a .ui-link {
    color:                  #2489CE;
    font-weight: bold;
}



.ui-btn-up-a {

/*
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: .9em;
    border-left: #5e7088 1px solid;
    border-right: #5e7088 1px solid;
    border-top: #34404e 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #34404e 1px solid;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
*/


    border: 1px solid       #222;
    background:             #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:                  #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #92a4bc), color-stop(0.5, #476997), color-stop(1.0, #4e6c92));
/*
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#777), to(#555));
*/
}
.ui-btn-up-a a.ui-link-inherit {
    color:                  #fff;
}
.ui-btn-hover-a {
    border: 1px solid       #000;
    background:             #444444;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:                  #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#888), to(#666));
}
.ui-btn-hover-a a.ui-link-inherit {
    color:                  #fff;
}
.ui-btn-down-a {
    border: 1px solid       #000;
    background:             #3d3d3d;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:                  #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#555), to(#7a7a7a));
}
.ui-btn-down-a a.ui-link-inherit {
    color:                  #fff;
}
.ui-btn-up-a,
.ui-btn-hover-a,
.ui-btn-down-a {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.ui-body-c {
    border: 1px solid       #B3B3B3;
    color:                  #333333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0    #fff;
    background:             #f0f0f0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#ddd));
}
.ui-body-c,
.ui-body-c input,
.ui-body-c select,
.ui-body-c textarea,
.ui-body-c button {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ui-body-c .ui-link-inherit {
    color:                  #333333;
}
.ui-body-c .ui-link {
    color:                  #2489CE;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ui-btn-up-c {
    border: 1px solid       #ccc;
    background:             #eee;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:                  #444;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #f6f6f6;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fdfdfd), to(#eee));
}
.ui-btn-up-c a.ui-link-inherit {
    color:                  #2F3E46;
}

.ui-btn-hover-c {
    border: 1px solid       #bbb;
    background:             #dadada;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:                  #101010;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px  #fff;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#dadada));
}
.ui-btn-hover-c a.ui-link-inherit {
    color:                  #2F3E46;
}
.ui-btn-down-c {
    border: 1px solid       #808080;
    background:             #fdfdfd;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:                  #111111;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px  #ffffff;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#fdfdfd));
}
.ui-btn-down-c a.ui-link-inherit {
    color:                  #2F3E46;
}
.ui-btn-up-c,
.ui-btn-hover-c,
.ui-btn-down-c {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.ui-corner-tl {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:         4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:     4px;
    border-top-left-radius:             4px;
}
.ui-corner-tr {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:        4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:    4px;
    border-top-right-radius:            4px;
}
.ui-corner-bl {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:      4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:  4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:          4px;
}
.ui-corner-br {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:     4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:         4px;
}
.ui-corner-top {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:         4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:     4px;
    border-top-left-radius:             4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:        4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:    4px;
    border-top-right-radius:            4px;
}
.ui-corner-bottom {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:      4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:  4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:          4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:     4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:         4px;
    }
.ui-corner-right {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:        4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:    4px;
    border-top-right-radius:            4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:     4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:         4px;
}
.ui-corner-left {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:         4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:     4px;
    border-top-left-radius:             4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:      4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:  4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:          4px;
}
.ui-corner-all {
    -moz-border-radius:                 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:              4px;
    border-radius:                      4px;
}



.ui-btn-corner-tl {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:         7px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:     7px;
    border-top-left-radius:             7px;
}
.ui-btn-corner-tr {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:        7px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:    7px;
    border-top-right-radius:            7px;
}
.ui-btn-corner-bl {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:      7px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:  7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:          7px;
}
.ui-btn-corner-br {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:     7px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:         7px;
}
.ui-btn-corner-top {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:         7px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:     7px;
    border-top-left-radius:             7px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:        7px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:    7px;
    border-top-right-radius:            7px;
}
.ui-btn-corner-bottom {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:      7px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:  7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:          7px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:     7px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:         7px;
}
.ui-btn-corner-right {
     -moz-border-radius-topright:       7px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:    7px;
    border-top-right-radius:            7px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:     7px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:         7px;
}
.ui-btn-corner-left {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:         7px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:     7px;
    border-top-left-radius:             7px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:      7px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:  7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:          7px;
}
.ui-btn-corner-all {
    -moz-border-radius:                 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:              7px;
    border-radius:                      7px;
}

/* ---------- Custom fixes ------------- */

.ui-btn-left[data-rel="back"] .ui-btn-inner,
.ui-btn-left[data-icon="back"] .ui-btn-inner,
.ui-btn-left[data-icon="arrow-l"] .ui-btn-inner {
    border-radius: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.ui-btn-left[data-rel="back"],
.ui-btn-left[data-icon="back"],
.ui-btn-left[data-icon="arrow-l"] {
    margin-top: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 16px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(../images/backButton.png) 0 5 0 13 stretch stretch;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px 16px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px 6px;
    border-width: 0 5px 0 13px;
    width: auto;
}
a.ui-btn-left[data-rel="back"] .ui-icon,
a.ui-btn-left[data-icon="back"] .ui-icon,
a.ui-btn-left[data-icon="arrow-l"] .ui-icon {
    display: none;
}

/*
.ui-btn-left[data-icon="home"] .ui-btn-inner {
    border-radius: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.ui-btn-left[data-icon="home"] {
    margin-top: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 16px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(../images/backButton.png) 0 5 0 13 stretch stretch;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px 16px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px 6px;
    border-width: 0 5px 0 13px;
    width: auto;
}
a.ui-btn-left[data-icon="home"] {
    display: none;
}
*/

div.itemLabel {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
div.itemValue {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.ui-content {
    min-height: 480px;
    background-image: url(../images/pinstripes.png);
}

.ui-header .ui-title {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.ui-header .ui-btn {
    margin-top: 2px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 320px){
    .ui-content ul li div.itemLabel {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .ui-content ul li div.itemValue {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

.errorMessage {
    color: red;
    text-align: center
}
```

Comment: I can’t reproduce the error you describe with the code you’ve supplied: - http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/z4G36/ Could you add some of your CSS to the JSFiddle above until the error shows up?

Comment: can your share the screen shot how it's appearing, isn't this because you wrapped the button by div and that div do not have any css definition.

Comment: paste your complete CSS file on a code sharing website and provide the link or use this as HTML for input <input type="submit" style="width:70px" value="Login" />

Comment: Do you have a live website where this can be viewed?

Comment: @Nitish: excellent, thanks. I’ve created [a standalone test page](http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/7846610/) with your code, but it doesn’t look like the screenshot you’ve supplied, even on my iPhone. What am I missing?

Comment: .content .standardButton , .content .standardButton, did you tried with fixed width rather than %

Comment: @Nitish: I did a bit of research and came up with something. re-look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Edited:
After a bit of Google I found that unless explicitly told, mobile Safari will change the appearance of buttons & controls to resemble a native Apple control.

Add this to your CSS file:

```
    .content form input[type="submit"] {
        width:70px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

By adding -webkit-appearance: none; we are telling mobile Safari that we explicitly don’t want our button to be styled like a native Apple UI control.

Hope it works!

Comment: It is because some other CSS property is conflicting with the one we just added. Use Firebug/Inspect element feature of your browser and look for that submit button's CSS property. 
Any link ?

Comment: I don't know an inch about firebug. I am developing cross platform rhodes app and deploying it on IPhone. I don't have much idea about css either. Can you provide some more help?

Comment: I think it is just because the input is not a direct descendant of div.content.  Try removing div.content from the style definition that bikerabhinav has given, just use input[type="submit"].  Hopefully if this works you can then make the style more specific.

Comment: @SGB doesn't matter, I did not use '>' operator so being a direct descendant isn't necessary.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

update your CSS file with the below then try

```
.submit input
{
  width:Npx !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define some styling to the parent div of the button, because the button has default width according to the text length of the value.

```
<div>
     <input type="submit" value="Login" />
   </div>
```